# Slider hides sub-menus

Tags: java

im using "menumatic" drop down menu. when i installed slider sub menus are gone. normally in "arsiv" menu i have 3 sub-menus but i can't see none of them. i don't know javascript or css, what can i do to fix this?

and these are menumatic codes;

http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=Lj3hWEs5

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a lot in a DotNetNuke skin I was using.  It ended up being something in the CSS.  Take a look at the z-index of the 3 sub-menues.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: thanks but i don't know any single word about javascript, i can't find these z-index values. how can i find my sub-menus z-index values?

Answer (score 0):

"z-index: x;" resolved my conflict. It was an easy fix to an issue many people seem to be having.

Try putting that under the CSS style for the drop-down ul.

Example

```
.navbar ul .subnav {
display: none;  
z-index: 3; 
}
```

You can play around with the number (x).